# How to style specific letters in string?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs3, styling

Let's assume that I receive a response from the **API** that contains a summary of the last matches of a given team.

Example response: `LLWWWWLWDWDWLW`

I want it to be in my div in specific style.

L should be stylized, its background should be **red (square shape)** and W should have a **green background**. The entire statement should be minimally separated from each other.

User has the option to change the team to check its recent matches.

I'm using **Vue.js**

Comment: Split the string, then work with "what you know needs to happen for individual letters". With that said though: remember that this is [a programming question](/help/on-topic) Q&A site, and your post doesn't actually contain a question, so... there's nothing for anyone here [to help with](/help/how-to-ask)? What single part of this multi-part description are you having problem with, and what code did you write that doesn't work the way you expected it to?

Comment: Split the string and put each letter in a ```<span></span>``` and style this span individually

Answer (score 1):

One quick solution with `v-for`:

```js
const mapColors = new Map([['W', 'green'], ['L', 'red'], ['D', 'yellow']])
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      matches: [{team: 'team 1', games: 'LLWWWWLWDWDWLW'}, {team: 'team 2', games: 'WWWWLWDLLWWWDW'}]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    setColor(c) {
      return mapColors.get(c)
    }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```css
.green {
  background: limegreen;
}
.red {
  background: lightcoral;
}
.yellow {
  background: gold;
}
.games {
  width: 1.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: .1em;
}
.match {
  margin-right: .5em;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-for="(match, idx) in matches" :key="idx">
    <span class="match">{{ match.team }}</span>
    <span v-for="(game, i) in match.games" :key="i">
      <span class="games" :class="setColor(game)">
        {{ game }}
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, very good answer, I understand the code + run code snippet helps a lot to verify it. Sending love